# В PyCharm весь текст подчеркивается, как будто все неправильно

Tags: python, pycharm

Как исправить ситуацию с тем что PyCharm 2018.3 весь код подчеркивается красным?

```
print("xxx")
x = 9
z = 10
cc = z + x
print("cc")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaxU имелось ввиду что полный абсурд! Любой правильный код якобы не правильный.

Comment: Да это весь код и в файле до этих строк, больше ничего нет.

Comment: Добавил скриншот. 11 ошибок и 3 варнинга :) Жесть...

Comment: Вы что-то меняли? Раньше все работало нормально? Интерпретатор для проекта  правильно настроен?

Comment: Я только установил его, ничего не настраивал, код запускается и работает. Было все сразу так из коробки.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html

Comment: @MaxU Может проблема в типе интерпретатора? или в версии 3.7?

Comment: Скорее всего, у Вас не выбран интерпретатор для проекта. Это можно сделать в правом нижнем углу (если будут варианты выбора) или в соответствующем разделе настроек.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Можете скриншот показать, а то у меня в правом нижнем углу нет выбора интерпретатора...

Comment: https://c2n.me/42ENgXE

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Если нет, то придётся зайти в настройки. `File -> Project -> Project Interpreter`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Дело в том что в настройках выставлено все... https://c2n.me/42ESPD0

Comment: Что пишет когда наводите на подчеркивание? Какие ошибки и предупреждения пишет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Ваш PyCharm ошибочно принимает `*.py` файлы за файлы `sass`, как видно на маленькой иконке файла. Для исправления нужно зайти в `File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types`, найти в списке `Recognized File Types` пункт `Sass Style Sheet` и затем, в поле `Registered Patterns` удалить всё, кроме `*.sass`.
[image: Скриншот]